# Allwos HTTPS request on My local server when useing react native app ,using Expo to build APK

Tags: react-native, google-sheets

I am using recat native to write my app, in development enviroment i can call my http request (Http//192.168.1.20:4040/login)  but when i build the app using expo the after putting the apk on physical device is not calling the api i am getting such an error when using flipper to inspect the logs "
qemu_pipe_open_ns:62: Could not connect to the 'pipe:qemud:network' service: Invalid argument"

important not :
1- i have check the network th device is in the same network that my server located also i used ping to test it works well .